# check if page was redirected or opened directly in php

Tags: php

Can I check if `page2.php` was opened directly or I was redirected from `page1.php`

I tried with `if(!header_sent()){}` but it didn't work.

please can anyone help me? thank you

Comment: I did it with a session check it works fine thank you everybody for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Session variable when a user visits page1.php, then on page2.php check if that session variable exists. If so, then the user was redirected from page1.php.

page1.php:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$_SESSION['page1'] = true;

// then the rest of your PHP code

?>
```

page2.php:

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if( $_SESSION['page1'] ) {
    $current_referrer = 'page1.php';
}

// then the rest of your PHP code

?>
```

Obviously, this method is assuming that you're only dealing with these two pages...
Hope this helps

Comment: What if hackerman get the cookie where the session is true? then he/she may bypass and execute the code within?

Answer (score 2):

I think this:

```
$referringSite = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

in combination with a little [parse_url](http://au.php.net/function.parse-url) will do the trick nicely for you.

Comment: its nothing to rely on, browser can send empty Referer

Answer (score 0):

`isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) and (mb_strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'page1.php')!==false)`  - this is solution.

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your code snippet?

Comment: isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) - check if isset variable Referrer. Then mb_strpos - check if in this value exists text page1.php              page1.php - is path from previous page